# How to add a plugin as a library to a plugin I made?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-plugin

I have a plugin that I am building, I would like to be able to override the `setting` of an other plugin, let's say `sbt-assembly`.

I would like in my `AutoPlugin` be able to do:

```
import sbtassembly

[...]

override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = {
  Seq(
    assembly := { /* override the task */ }
  )
}
```

I have tried to add in `./build.sbt` :

```
libraryDependencies += "com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.9"
```

But I get

```
(update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.9: not found
```

I tried to add it in `./project/plugins.sbt` but if I understand correctly, that will add it as a build tool to build my plugin not as something accessible within the code of the plugin and it seems that I am right since I cannot access `sbtassembly` package.

Any tips ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution !

It is to add

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.9")
```

in `build.sbt` not in `project/plugins.sbt`.

I guess `sbt-assembly` is not a library, it is a plugin. So to add a plugin, you need to use `addSbtPlugin`.

And since you want it in the code, not in the compiler, you put it in `build.sbt`, not in `project/plugins.sbt`.